# Is it possible to parse csv columns containing arrays with vectorized Pandas code?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

The following code generates a CSV and then parses it again. Column b contains an array of integers for every field.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np


# Create CSV
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a=[1,2,3],
    b=[[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
))
s = df.to_csv()

# ,a,b
# 0,1,[1]
# 1,2,"[1, 2]"
# 2,3,"[1, 2, 3]"

def parse(s):
    return np.fromstring(s[1:-1], sep=", ", dtype=int)

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), converters=dict(b=parse))
```

The question is now if it is possible to vectorize/speed up the parsing. I am suspecting that this might be possible by specifying a dtype for column b, but I couldn't figure out what dtype this would be.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is `.csv` a requirement? If you want object permanence between I/O operations there are better file formats that can store python objects.

Comment: The reason why I currently use CSV is because I can easily append to it (line by line) and read it from various programming languages (python, c++, node, java). However, I want to test if I can use parquet instead. But parquet is not really optimized for the append use case I guess. Would you recommend another format?

Comment: I have just run some tests and appending to Parquet leads to much bigger files. Also, there is no official Parquet writer for node.

Comment: Ah I was mostly wondering if everything was fully within python. Since that's not the case things like `.pkl` probably aren't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this converters working?  Then I'd suggest sticking with it.

The original DF has an object dtype column containing lists of varying size.  The save writes the `str` version of those lists.  Your convert produces an array

```
In [155]: np.fromstring("[1,2,3]"[1:-1], sep=", ", dtype=int)                                  
Out[155]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

`eval` (or the 'safer' `ast` equivalent) produces a list:

```
In [156]: eval("[1, 2, 3]")                                                                    
Out[156]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Beware that if the original had arrays instead of lists, the string would not work as well.

```
In [157]: str(_155)                                                                            
Out[157]: '[1 2 3]'
```

It's missing the handy comma.  And worse, it may contain `...` is the array is large enough.

This has come up often, often because people unintentionally saved a frame with these list or array elements.  So far I have not seen a pretty alternative - at least not if you want a human-readable csv.

To some degree a dataframe with list or array elements is an aberration.  The column dtype will be object, and fast numpy operations are not possible.  But pandas uses object dtype for strings as well.

Also with lists that vary in length, you can't make a n-d array.  It can only be a list or object dtype array.  The calculation speed of a numeric array is gone.

Comment: Unfortunately, eval/literal_eval is ~6 times slower than my parse